# Multi-stage passive filter design

Tags: rf, filter, passive-networks, passive-filter

I'm playing around with some simple RF beacons.  Many of these use a multi-stage LC ladder to filter the outgoing signal after passing through a class C amp.

Can someone point me to a good reference/book discussing how these filters (including different topologies) are designed? I know that tables are often used when calculating these filters. A brief explanation of how these tables are generated would help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Books:**

1.) R. Saal: The Desigh of Filters Using the Catalogue of Normalized Low-pass Filters

2.) A.I. Zverev: Handbook on filtering Synthesis

These books contain tables for the various passive RLC LOWPASS structures.
For other filter types (highpass, bandpass,...) you have to apply transformation formulas. More than that, all values for the passive elements are normalized and must be de-normalized for different pole/zero positions.

**Simulation programs:**
Because it is a rather involved procedure to use the tables it is strongly recommended to use one of the available filter design programs.
The "AADE Filer Design" program is available for free from www.aade.com.

Comment: This looks like a good starting point, thanks for the help.